# Kotlin coroutines and SecurityException

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm using Retrofit's coroutines adapter and I see that, if the network call fails because the URL is incorrect, the try/catch block will catch it, but if I remove the Internet permission so that we get a SecurityException, the app crashes instead.

This is the code handling the response from retrofit:

```
override suspend fun execute(): Result<IpAddress> = try {
    val result = dataRepository.getIpAddress().await()
    Result.Success(result)
} catch (throwable: Throwable) {
    if (throwable is JobCancellationException) {
        throw throwable
    }
    Result.Error(throwable)
}
```

The repository is simply

```
override suspend fun getIpAddress(): Deferred<IpAddress> = dataService.getIpAddress()
```

with

```
interface DataService {
    @GET("/?format=json")
    fun getIpAddress(): Deferred<IpAddress>
}
```

Why do exceptions like UnknownHostException get trapped but SecurityException crashes the app?

This is the crash log

```
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.coroutines, PID: 12465
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:151)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:214)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 26 more
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-09 12:27:25.467 12465 12495 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Side point: do not use `Result<IpAddress>` as the return type of your `suspend fun`. Simply use `IpAddress`.

Comment: Result is a sealed class that allows me to wrap both Success and Error as a Result class, so the client can then handle the outcome of the call.

Comment: Unless you have the entire codebase committed to FP idioms and higher-order functions, it will be much more natural to throw exceptions to signal error. Not to say far less hassle to handle many errors in bulk, at a single point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in one case Retrofit catches it internally and passes it back as an error, knowing you may wish to handle it.  In the other case it doesn't catch it and it crashes the app.  There's no way to change this short of forking Retrofit as it happens on their internal thread, just keep the internet permission in there.

Comment: But shouldn't the try/catch wrapping the await() call catch the exception?

Comment: No.  A try catch on thread A does not catch exceptions that occur on thread B.

Comment: I think it _should_ catch the exception because Retrofit should propagate it. Swallowing exceptions, including `Error`s, is never to anyone's benefit.

Comment: I do suggest to file a bug to Retrofit. You can easily create a reproducer without coroutines at all. Retrofit should propagate all exceptions to the user code, leaving decision on how to handle them to the user.

Comment: @RomanElizarov It isn't a bug.  Its a philosophical choice.  Not finding a host isn't really an exception, its an expected possible outcome.  The user could have passed in an invalid url.  This is a programming bug making the operation impossible.  Throwing an exception is the correct move.